# Cant delete document from print queue, only displaying "deleting"

Tags: windows-10, printer

I tried to print a webpage, but it wasnt exactly printer friendly so the printer printed a result I was not satisfied with.

I opened the paper tray so the printer couldn´t continue and started the printer administration tool by double clicking the printer icon in the system tray.

Then I pressed <kbd>Delete</kbd>

I expected the print job to be removed from the print queue but it will not go away. It only displays "Deleting". Why?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

(Note: You must have administrator rights on the computer.)

To clear the print queue if a document is stuck :

- Run `services.msc` to display the Services window
- Scroll down to Print Spooler
- Right click it and select Stop
- Navigate to `C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS` and delete all files
- In the Services window, restart the Print Spooler service by clicking
  Start in the left pane when it is highlighted.

The print spooler queue is now cleared. Print the file again.

Comment: Do you know why the GUI isn´t programmed to do the things on the list when I try to remove a job?

Comment: I guess that the Print Spooler is stuck on some printer request, which is why it has to be shutdown in order to delete the files.

Comment: But the "deleting" thing is happening every time I try to remove a print job.

Comment: I would guess again that this problem is related to the printer driver. Check you have the latest driver from the manufacturer. If the problem still occurs, contact the Support team of the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a set of commands that will clear the Print Spooler. This works on properly working Windows machines from at least Vista forward to current Windows.

Click Start. Type Command . Right-click “Command Prompt” and select “Run as administrator“  (so you need admin credentials).

Type `net stop spooler` then press “Enter“.

Type `del %systemroot%\System32\spool\printers\* /Q` then press “Enter“.

(OR  `del C:\windows\system32\spool\printers\* /Q`)

Type `net start spooler` then press “Enter“.

The print queue on your Windows should now be cleared.

I would also restart the computer when this is done.

Printing can resume after this.

Comment: Use the short list of commands to clear the spooler before restarting. I also clear the spooler like this when installing / reinstalling a printer

Comment: AFAIR, you can also find the process `spwow64` and kill it.

Comment: Do you know why the GUI isn´t programmed to do all this when I try to remove a job?

Comment: You need to use the command list I gave you. GUI won't do the Queue clearing.

Comment: Also, most of Microsoft GUI tools are made for end users. A user selects Print, it doesn't for whatever reason, and then the end user may restart or call for help.  "Help" will happily use the command lines to fix the issue. Providing the ability within the GUI would not likely be used by many people.  Human nature.

Comment: But if the GUI removed the print job at the same time as I pressed the delete key and ejected the last partially printed paper (if any) the commands would not be needed?

Comment: If you can delete the job via the GUI, well and good. But you said you could not so the commands are needed.